# The index of maximum element in an array of tuples

Tags: python

How can I find the index of the largest value for tuples in a list in a short number of code lines?

I could do that using two for loops but I could not make it shorter.

for example:

```
[(0, 0.51634575), (1, 0.113904804), (2, 0.7697494)]
[(0, 0.20560692), (1, 0.141724408), (2, -0.112972)]
[(0, 0.11324576), (1, 0.77262518), (2, 0.11417362)]
```

should return

```
2
0
1
```

which are the first values (the indices) of the tuples.

here is what I tried:

```
a= [(0, 0.11324576), (1, 0.77262518), (2, 0.11417362)]

max = max([x[1] for x in a])
id=-1
for x in a:
    if x[1] == max:
        id = x[0]
        break

print(id)
```

Comment: "I could do that using two for loops" <- Please show us this attempt so that we can better assist you.

Comment: Would be great if you can include your code as well so we can see which parts to improve on.

Comment: Largest based on what value within the tuple?

Comment: something like [max(a) for a in [max(b) for b in list_of_tupled]]]

Comment: updated the question with my code

Comment: @CoryKramer is right, you should define "largest tuple". Is it according to the sum of the values ? Their product ? Their division ? Or whatever operation ?

Comment: why do you expect the result 2 0 1? In every list the max number (2) is in the last entry. Are you considering only the last element of the tuple?

Comment: @CoryKramer those are different lists., so the largest based on the second value of the tuple

Comment: Is the first element of each tuple always equivalent to the tuple's position in the list?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak yes

Answer (score 2):

You can use the operator `itemgetter()` as the key in the function `max()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

l = [[(0, 0.51634575), (1, 0.113904804), (2, 0.7697494)], [(0, 0.20560692), (1, 0.141724408), (2, -0.112972)], [(0, 0.11324576), (1, 0.77262518), (2, 0.11417362)]]

get1 = itemgetter(1)
[max(i, key=get1)[0] for i in l]
# [2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but this should work:

```
l = [(0, 0.51634575), (1, 0.113904804), (2, 0.7697494)]
l[l.index((_, max([tuple[1] for tuple in l])))][0]
```

Output:

```
2
```

Of course, it's debatable whether this does not constitute two for loops.

Another solution that only uses a single for loop would look like this:

```
max_index = -1
max_val = -1
for (index, value) in l:
    if value > max_val:
        max_index = index
        max_val = value
return max_index
```

Answer (score 1):

For one list:

```
b = [(0, 0.11324576), (1, 0.77262518), (2, 0.11417362)]

n = [x[1] for x in b]
print(b[n.index(max(n))][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate:

```
i_max=0
for i,t in enumerate(a):
    if (a[i][1] > a[i_max][1]):
        i_max = i
print(i_max)
```

---

Without using enumerate (assuming first element of tuple always equals the index of the tuple in the list of tuples):

```
i_max=0
for t in a:
    if (t[1] > a[i_max][1]):
        i_max = t[0]
print(i_max)
```

Answer (score 0):

if data is likethis

```
a = [[(0, 0.51634575), (1, 0.113904804), (2, 0.7697494)],
[(0, 0.20560692), (1, 0.141724408), (2, -0.112972)],
[(0, 0.11324576), (1, 0.77262518), (2, 0.11417362)]]
```

then

```
result = [max(lis,key = lambda x :x[1])[0] for lis in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Baseline:

```
test_set = [
  [(0, 0.51634575), (1, 0.113904804), (2, 0.7697494)],
  [(0, 0.20560692), (1, 0.141724408), (2, -0.112972)],
  [(0, 0.11324576), (1, 0.77262518), (2, 0.11417362)],
]
```

---

This is the shortest version without too much code golfing:

```
for test in test_set:
  c, v = zip(*test)
  result = c[v.index(max(v))]
  print(result)
```

---

And because code golfing is actually fun:

```
for t in test_set:print(max(t,key=lambda x:x[1])[0])
```

---

This is the most runtime and probably also most memory efficient version:

```
for test in test_set:
  max_elem = test[0]
  for tup in test:
    if tup[1] > max_elem[1]:
      max_elem = tup
  print(max_elem[0])
```

---

Results of all above snippets:

```
2
0
1
```

Comment: With `index()` you get `O(N^2)` time complexity. The same efficiency when you use double `for` loop.

Comment: @MykolaZotko yep. That's why I included the last snippet as the best performing one - it should be O(N)